# DWR sometimes die on the GAE server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dwr

I'm creating web app on the Google App Engine. For the AJAX calling I use DWR.
Latest DWR version doesn't work fine with gae, because of that I work with 2.0.6 version of the DWR.

On the local machine application works good. But on the Google server some methods called with errors. I only get errors in browser console (server logs are clear):
[image]

Any ideas? Why the behavior on the local and the server machines is different?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you unless you include the code that's causing the exception.

Comment: Nick, I found the issue reasons. It is the mistake in my server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found mistake in my server side code.

DWR 2 works fine for me. The question is closed.

Excuse me for your time.

Comment: Why not post how you solved the problem, so others in the future can see what you did?

Comment: Because the problem was in my app business logic. Some fields were null and I try to use them as not null.