# DWR with Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dwr

I created one google app engine project. There I configured DWR(DirectWebRemoting).
I have created one  ajax functionality which will checks the username and password of the user. But it does give me any output rather it gives Error:

```
dwr is not defined
Source File: http://localhost:8081/dwr.jsp
Line: 16
```

Where as it works fine in Tomcat web application.

So My question is that does Google app engine not support DWR configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DWR is compatible with GAE according to ["Will it play in Java"](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava#Direct_Web_Remoting_%28DWR%29) (broken link. possibly: [a list of GAE-compatible java libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist)) page.

Several links to threads with proof of success and potential limitations:

- [thread about "DWR 3 RC1"](http://dwr.2114559.n2.nabble.com/DWR3RC1-threads-td2646984.html) from "users@dwr.java.net"
- StackOverflow question ["DWR sometimes die on the GAE server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552293/dwr-sometimes-die-on-the-gae-server)

Most useful post in "DWR 3 RC1" thread is [this one](http://dwr.2114559.n2.nabble.com/DWR3RC1-threads-td2646984.html#a3565562) (about potential problems).

1. Do you require reverse ajax? (Current implementation uses a thread to clean up expired sessions. Current implementation uses javax.swing.event.EventListenerList which is blacklisted by GAE/J.)
2. Do you require file upload? (Can potentially write to disk)
3. Do you require file download? (Current implementation uses a thread to clean up expired downloads)

If you don't need anything from the above, then you could replace problematic classes with dummy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported, but the same functionality is offered by channels :

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/